# How to json strinfigy a function instance in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

If I have this code

```
var node = function(n) {

    var name = n;
    var children = [];
    var finished = false;
    var failed = false;

    this.getName = function() {
        return name
    };
    this.downloadData = function(obj) {

    };

    this.getChildren = function() {
        return children;
    };
    this.setChildren = function(c) {
        Array.prototype.push.apply(children, c);
    };
    this.isFinished = function() {
        return finished;
    };
    this.setFinished = function() {
        finished = true;
    }
    this.isFailed = function() {
        return failed;
    }
    this.setFailed = function() {
        failed = true;
    }
};
```

How can I convert this into an object like:

```
var a = new node("a");
var j = JSON.stringify(a);
```

result

```
{"name":"a","children":[],"finished":false,"failed":false}
```

thanks

Comment: Fortunately it's not possible.

Comment: I think the title is poorly chosen. It sounds like you want to convert a function to a string, where you seem to want to convert an object created via `new .....` to convert to JSON. FYI, it doesn't matter where the object came from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be done by implementing the `toJSON` function.

> If an object being stringified has a property named toJSON whose value
>   is a function, then the toJSON() method customizes JSON
>   stringification behavior: instead of the object being serialized, the
>   value returned by the toJSON() method when called will be serialized.
>   [- Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior)

eg:

```
var node = function(n) {

  var name = n;
  var children = [];
  var finished = false;
  var failed = false;

  this.toJson = function toJson() {
    return {"name":name ... };
  } 

 }
```

Comment: but what do u call on "children"?

Comment: That depends on what the children are, your question just indicates that its an array.

Comment: children can contain more nodes.

Answer (score 2):

You need *object* **properties** instead of **variables**.

So, instead of declaring `var name = n;`, you would declare `this.name = n;`. Which would make it look something like

```
var node = function(n) {
    this.name = n;
    this.children = [];
    this.finished = false;
    this.failed = false;
    ///other functions here
}
```

Comment: This would change the `access modifiers` of the variables from being private/local to public. Might not be what OP intended them to be, seing he/she has created get/set for them.

Comment: Ah, that's an interesting point. In which case, your solution is definitely the way to go. If the the end result was a flat JSON object, I'm wondering why the getters/setters would be necessary. You could not use them when the JSON string was parsed later.